# Is it possible to get the client's ip address from a service class (outside of controller) in ASP.NET Core 3.1?

Tags: asp.net-core-3.1

I have seen a lot of posts that detail how to get IP address while inside the controller, but I have some C# service classes that do most of the work, which are called from the controller.

I need to be able to obtain the client's IP address, etc. from these service classes and would prefer to not have to send the context from the controller to the service class.  Is this possible?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to pass `HttpContext` through method's argument. Simple and straightforward solution. Not sure about pros and cons of this, sadly.

Anoher way, [according to ASP.NET Core 3.1 documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-3.1#use-httpcontext-from-custom-components), you can inject `IHttpContextAccessor` and access `HttpContext` through it. This would be more elegant way, IMHO.